# Why does blender take longer to re-mesh certain objects?

Tags: mesh

I typically don't ask questions for which there are well documented answers, but this one has had me stumped for over 2 days now.

I generated multiple objects, some of them possessing 300k+ faces and others with faces in only the hundreds. Blender has no problem instantly remeshing the larger objects. It takes about 5-10 seconds. A few objects, in particular, seem to completely crash the system, taxing out 16Gb of memory to 100% and using 50% an AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950X 16-Core Processor while GPU use sits at 0%. Eventually, it crashes -- and the object was no more than 300 faces. Literally a glorified cube. I have tried this exercise with many, many objects, including a simple wooden shelf .OBJ downloaded directly from TurboSquid. No, Blender could not remesh the shelf. It crashed on that one too.

Here is a sample .blend file that re-produces the error. You can re-produce it yourself by doing nothing more than importing an .OBJ or .FBX file with more than 1,000 faces and trying to re-mesh it:

[image]

I am new to this tool, and just downloaded 2.83. I am aware it is poorly designed and has suffered crippling UI flaws for years -- but this type of operation should not be a challenge. Before I table Blender for good, would anyone have any insights as to why this might be happening? I literally can't remesh any simple objects. I have to add a few hundred thousand faces to it before Blender is happy. We wanted to use it for a POC before trying to drum up funding for Maya.

It makes absolutely no sense. Blender makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: TBH that sounds like a bug. I would create a test example that cause the issue every time and submit a bug report: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Comment: Hello and welcome! No idea what your object topology looks like that you are  starting with.Without images and/or a  [*simplified blend file*](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) it is hard to give a good answer. Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/181881/edit) your question and add more information to your question.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a sample .blend file. All that is required to cause the problem is to Add Modifier > Remesh. It will then go crazy, ramp memory up to 99% for about 5-10 minutes and/ or hang the computer and then crash. It does this for nearly every .OBJ have tried to import. I wasn't seeing this problem before upgrading to 2.83, though I'd be hard pressed to go back to an earlier version. The interface is unpalatable. I just now downloaded a Maya LT trial. If I can do this task in under 10 minutes, Blender is off the table permanently.

Comment: Your issue may be system specific, remeshing your object at 8 octree took 7 seconds. Yes maya and houdini even can do some things better or faster, (I use both) . Houdini would just be vdb and done. but some things blender is much better for and worth using and keeping around.

Comment: Maya LT could even open the .OBJ file, so it's not going to be a viable too either. Sounds like we will have to give Houdini a try. I am surprised these tools are not compatible with NVIDIA / Ryzen systems. They are standard these days.